# What's new in SP2016 regarding Information Rights Management?

Tags: 2016, irm

According to [New and improved features in SharePoint Server 2016](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/what-s-new/new-and-improved-features-in-sharepoint-server-2016), Information Rights Management is labelled as new feature in SP2016. However I cannot find anything new compare to SP2013. Clicking the links goto SP2013 or SharePoint online pages.

Also, I cannot find any official article talk about how to setup IRM in SP2016. Could you please advise?

Comment: hmmm, is it a Microsoft marketing lie or just a mistake no one point out in last 3 years?